# how do I validate a particular script in persent in page source using selenium?

Tags: selenium

In page source I have script tags as below,
how to validate in selenium that particular scripts are persent???

```html
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.4.8"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.4.8"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.4.8"></script>
```

Comment: What is your programming language? What have you tried?

Comment: @Andersson,I am using java..I have tried "driver.findElements(By.tagName("script"))"..which gives be all script elements in page source...and then I will have to use some kind of for loop, which will find script with attributeName matching with the required src

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search for attribute src within a script. i.e. finding element by attribute

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//script[@src='/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8']"))
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//script[contains(@src,'/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8')]")
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("script[src='/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8']"))
```